# What did Rey hear at the end of The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Towards the end of *The Rise of Skywalker*, Rey hears voices

> of Jedi past.

What characters' voices were they?

Comment: are they not in the credits? I've not seen it myself yet but know what the spoilers say about it.

Comment: @NKCampbell They were, but I didn't catch them and I haven't seen a complete list.

Comment: Please place the "SPOLIER" tag in the question titles, as many of us have not seen the film yet, in the US and elsewhere (12/20 release date).

Comment: @MissouriSpartan we don’t put spoiler in titles or tags. You can ignore tags and hide them if you don’t want to see questions in a tag.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/224946/4918 "Were these Star Wars characters voiced by their original actors?" for a complete answer that lists both the Jedi characters and the actors voicing them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This screenshot I've found shows the names in the credits and matches with who I remember with some extras:

[image: Credits screenshot with the names quoted below]

- Yoda
- Mace Windu
- Kanan Jarrus from *Star Wars Rebels*
- Qui-Gon Jinn
- Obi-Wan Kenobi (Both the Original and prequel trilogy versions)
- Anakin Skywalker
- Luminara Unduli
- Ahsoka Tano
- Aayla Secura
- Adi Gallia

Comment: Wait, Ahsoka said many times in Rebels she wasn't a Jedi though, how is she able to speak to her?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie yet. Does this mean Ahsoka is dead by the time of the sequel trilogy? IIRC, it has been stated that she was alive during the original trilogy, at least

Comment: @RemyLebeau She survives until the end of the Battle of Endor, if the ending of Rebels is true.

Comment: @CBredlow right, but what about after that? If her voice is speaking to Rey in TRoS, does that imply she died sometime between Rebels and TRoS? I guess so, [according to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano#The_Rise_of_Skywalker): "*Ahsoka Tano makes a cameo appearance in "The Rise of Skywalker" as one of the Jedi Force Ghosts that help Rey in the battle against Palpatine.*" So, unless she is projecting herself like Luke did in TLJ, I guess she had to die :-(

Comment: I mean, it's a dangerous galaxy and she must have been like 60 too by then.

Comment: @CBredlow Ahsoka isn't a Jedi by name but she is clearly strong in the Force