# Were these Star Wars characters voiced by their original actors?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, the-rise-of-skywalker

Who were

> the Jedi

that spoke to Rey? And how many of them were voiced by their original actors?

The list of them were in the credits, but scrolled by too quickly.

Comment: At least partially answered (list of names) in [this earlier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224685/what-did-rey-hear-at-the-end-of-the-rise-of-skywalker).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes.

> **Obi-Wan Kenonbi:** "These are your final steps, Rey. Rise, and take them."
> **Anakin Skywalker:** "Rey."
> **Ahsoka Tano:** "Rey."
> **Kanan Jarrus:** "Rey."
> **Anakin:** "Bring back the balance, Rey, as I did."
> **Luminara Unduli:** "The light. Find the light, Rey."
> **Qui-Gon Jinn:** "Every Jedi who ever lived, lives in you."
> **Anakin:** "The Force surrounds you, Rey."
> **Aayla Secura:** "Let it guide you."
> **Mace Windu:** "Feel the Force flowing through you, Rey."
> **Anakin:** "Let it lift you."
> **Adi Galia:** "Rise, Rey."
> **Qui-Gon:** "We stand behind you, Rey."
> **Obi-Wan:** "Rey."
> **Yoda:** "Rise in the Force, Rey."
> **Kanan:** "In the heart of a Jedi lies their strength."
> **Obi-Wan:** "Rise."
> **Qui-Gon:** "Rise."
> **Luke Skywalker:** "Rey, the Force will be with you. Always."
> <sub>[Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-jedi-voice-cameos-rise-skywalker-dialogue/)</sub>

[According to IMBD](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2527338/fullcredits/cast), the following voice actors contributed to that scene, all of whom acted or voiced the original characters

**Mark Hamill - Luke Skywalker**

[image: Mark Hamill][image: Luke Skywalker]

**Sir Alec Guinness/Ewan McGregor - Obi Wan Kenobi**

[image: Sir Alec Guinness][image: Old Ben Kenobi]

[image: Ewan McGregor][image: Obi Wan Kenobi]

**Frank Oz - Yoda**

[image: Frank Oz][image: Yoda]

**Hayden Christensen - Anakin Skywalker**

[image: Hayden Christensen][image: Anakin Skywalker]

**Samuel L. Jackson - Mace Windu**

[image: Samuel L. Jackson][image: Mace Windu]

**Liam Neeson - Qui-Gon Jinn**

[image: Liam Neeson][image: Qui-Gon Jinn]

**Olivia d'Abo - Luminara Unduli**

[image: Olivia d'Abo][image: Luminara Unduli]

**Ashley Eckstein - Ahsoka Tano**

[image: Ashley Eckstein][image: Ahsoka Tano]

**Jennifer Hale - Aayla Secura**

[image: Jennifer Hale][image: Aayla Secura]

**Angelique Perrin - Adi Gallia**

[image: Angelique Perrin][image: Adi Gallia]

**Freddie Prinze Jr. - Kannan Jarus**

[image: Freddie Prinze Jr.][image: Kannan Jarus]

Comment: [spoilers] umm, where the babu frik is LEIA?!?! The trailer implied that Luke would say "the Force with be with you..." and Leia would say "always". I'm not ok. They need to add her in there for the Blu-ray edition long with adding Ben Solo at the end on Tatooine.

Comment: She wasn't a force ghost yet.

Answer (score 4):

IMDB has the full cast including voice credits.
https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2527338/fullcredits/cast

All the voice actors were ones who voiced them previously either live action or animated.