# How did Sir Alec Guinness' voice appear in The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, the-rise-of-skywalker

Towards the end of *The Rise of Skywalker*, in the final confrontation scene between

> Rey and Palpatine

Rey hears the voices of many previous Jedi. [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224911/were-these-star-wars-characters-voiced-by-their-original-actors) tells us that Alec Guinness is credited with one of the lines but he [died in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alec_Guinness#Death), well before the character of Rey was developed.

If he'd said "Use the Force" or something similar, or the character had been part of the original trilogy (and so they'd had unused lines they could reuse) then I'd understand but short of some techno-jedi I'm confused.

How did Sir Alec Guinness have a credited speaking role in a film more than 19 years after his death?

Comment: +1. I don’t think it says in the linked question. Which words were said in the voice of Alec Guinness (as opposed to Ewen McGregor)?

Comment: Nevermind, just watched the vid below with Jimmy Kimmel.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> **McGregor:** But they used, they got Alec Guinness to do "Rey." Which is extraordinary because he's not alive anymore.
>
> **Kimmel:** JJ's really impressive. Yeah.
>
> **McGregor:** Amazing what they can do these days. But! They found a, they got a line of him as Alec...Obi-Wan Kenobi saying "afraid" and they just cut the "a" and the "d" off and they got that "Rey" and then they used that. So Alec Guinness is saying "Rey" and then I say "these are your first steps."

Comment: As a side note: even if they did not have that part of audio, today it is possible to clone voices with relatively little effort: https://towardsdatascience.com/you-can-now-speak-using-someone-elses-voice-with-deep-learning-8be24368fa2b?gi=e810230226bb . I wonder if the splicing was done for legal (copyright) reasons.

Comment: @SredniVashtar: It's an old, tried, simple, and workable method - the hardest part is finding source material. For a single syllable, this is relatively easy.

Comment: It's a good thing her name is just one common syllable.  They'd probably have a harder time getting him to say e.g. "Kylo", (although if they had to do that, they'd probably just use "Ben")

Comment: Plot twist: `Rey` was named that because that was one of they syllables they had Alec Guiness saying

Comment: @Piskvor here's an update: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sR1rU3gLzQ (from the Two Minutes Papers youtube channel: "This AI clones your voice after listening for 5 seconds"). I wonder what Orwell would have made of that... (deepfake+voice cloning = the party IS actually right! Do not believe your eyes and ears)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, not that hard. "Obi-Wan Kenobi. Obi-Wan... Now, that's a name I've not heard in a long time. A long time." You've got all the required phonemes in that one line of dialogue to splice the name "Kylo".

Answer (score 28):

Voice splicing.

They take lines he had in the original trilogy and take out specific words and syllables to make him say what they want. For example in *The Force Awakens* you can hear his voice say 'Rey' during her vision, this was taken from the word 'afraid' which has that syllable in it, he said this word in *A New Hope*.

Comment: "Hello there! Come here my little friend. Don’t be afraid."

Comment: Reminds me of when EA claimed Marlon Brando was doing voice work for The Godfather video game. They played a few samples from the movie to justify this weak claim and used a soundalike for everything else.